# Scala can't convert Java map keySet to a Sequence type

Tags: java, scala, collections

I have the following Scala code:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val threads : Seq[Thread] = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().asScala
```

That produces the following compiler error:

> "*Expression of type mutable.Set[Thread] doesn't conform to expected type Seq[Thread].*"

Whats the fix here?

Comment: If you require a `Seq` you can use `toSeq` as in  `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().asScala.toSeq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `keySet` returns a set, so `asScala` will convert to a Scala set. Remove the return type.

```
val threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().asScala
```

If you really need a `Seq`, the add `toSeq`.

```
val threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().asScala.toSeq
```